# Writing a custom panel plugin for grafana

Tags: grafana

So I need to write a custom grafana plugin, that works like a funnel. I decided to try and integrate  [this](https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel) funnel. Note that it is supposed to get the data from a mysql Server and use it just as a table and not as time series.

So far I read the grafana documentation and then watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y31wnP_jDBY). In the video a dataFormat is declared in the plugin.json file, however when I checked other working Plugins I didn't see that part written in the plugin.json. The GitHub repos in the video are also gone. I stumbled upon [this one](https://github.com/grafana/simple-react-panel) though, so then I copied it in the `data/plugin` directory. I restarted the Server and it was detected but when I tried making a new Panel I got an error saying that it could not be found. I was planning on starting with this example and then working my way towards integrating the funnel part but I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your problem with the same actions and got same error:

> Panel plugin not found: myorgid-simple-panel

Just a guess: there is a dependency section in plugin.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"grafanaVersion": "6.3.x",
"plugins": []
}
```

My Grafana version is v6.2.5. Isn't this plugin template for future Grafana release (master or developement version)?

Comment: Tom is right. Clone the grafana repo and checkout to version v6.3.0-beta2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with simple-react-panel. To solve it, I ran in the *simple-react-panel-master* directory :

```
npm i @grafana/toolkit
npm i @grafana/ui
yarn build
```

and after I restart grafana service